# Rails 2.3.5 threadsafe! breaks my migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, thread-safety

I'm using jruby-1.5.3 with a rails 2.3.5 app.  I've just started playing around with thread safety using:

```
config.threadsafe!
config.eager_load_paths << "#{RAILS_ROOT}/lib"
```

Which works fine, I just noticed however on deployment to my staging environment (which has the same config as production) that I get undefined constants.  For instance, a migration that adds another role to a Role table:

```
class AddSuperAdminRole < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    Role.create :rolename => 'super_admin'
  end
end
```

throws a:

```
uninitialized constant AddSuperAdminRole::Role
```

It works fine in dev environment because i'm not running that multithreaded so I know that's the issue.  I've tried eager loading the app/models path also but that didn't work.  How do I get migrations running with threadsafety?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

upgrading to 2.3.10 fixed this.

Comment: Is there a blog post or something about this?  Scanning the commits I can't see a fix, and I'd really like to see if it's in the newer version of rails 3.  Thanks!

Comment: no didn't see a blog post at all, just searched the source...  can't actually find the commit currently but i'll keep you posted when i do

Answer (score 0):

From ticket [#2506](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/2506-models-are-not-loaded-in-migrations-when-configthreadsafe-is-set) on the Rails Lighthouse site. Below i linked the threadsafe method in Rails. You'll see that `config.dependency_loading` is set to false because it's not thread safe and therefore the migrations are getting their dependencies auto-loaded.

```
# Enable threaded mode. Allows concurrent requests to controller actions and
# multiple database connections. Also disables automatic dependency loading
# after boot, and disables reloading code on every request, as these are
# fundamentally incompatible with thread safety.
    def threadsafe!
      self.preload_frameworks = true
      self.cache_classes = true
      self.dependency_loading = false
      self.action_controller.allow_concurrency = true
      self
    end
```

Here's Joshua Peek's response to the problem in comments to the ticket:

> I would suggest requiring the models
>   the you need in the migration, or
>   better including the model definition
>   again so the migration doesn't depend
>   on its existence.

Comment: ya i read some of that, also found a post on the 2.3.10 upgrade, which includes a fix.  So i just upgraded.